# demonstrate that $v_3 \perp (v_1-v_2)$

Tags: linear-algebra

$\bar{v}_1 \perp (\bar{v}_2-\bar{v}_3)$ and $\bar{v}_2 \perp (\bar{v}_3-\bar{v}_1)$ therefore $\bar{v}_3 \perp (\bar{v}_1-\bar{v}_2)$

By applying the dot product to $\bar{v}_1$ and $(\bar{v}_2-\bar{v}_3)$ and $\bar{v}_2$ and $(\bar{v}_1-\bar{v}_2)$ and setting the resulting equations equal, I got:

$\bar{v}_3= \frac{2\bar{v}_1\bar{v}_2}{\bar{v}_2+\bar{v}_1}$

Now, I don't know where to go. Could anyone help?

Comment: This is false as stated. Take $\overline{v}_1 = (1, 0, 0)$, $\overline{v}_2 = (0, 1, 0)$ and $\overline{v}_3 = (0, 0, 1)$.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot derive 
$$
v_3 = v_1 - v_2
$$
from the information given. For instance, if 
\begin{align}
v_1 = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}\\
v_2 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}\\
v_3 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

then your conditions hold, but the conclusion does not. Furthermore, your conditions are symmetric in $v_1$ and $v_2$, so swapping them would have to show that $v_3 = v_2 - v_1$ as well, which is nonsense.

I think you need to tell us more about your vectors.

Comment: Yes, I just noticed that I had noted it down incorrectly, thus I can't get the answer. I'll play with it for a bit now I've noticed that.